# Compacts in radial topology

Tags: general-topology

Hi: I’m trying to understand the radial topology of the plane. In this topology a set is open if, for every point in the set, there is an open line segment in every direction from the point that stays with in the set.

What can be said about the  compact sets in this topology? Is there any compact set with interior? I have managed to prove that the radial topology restricted over circles is the discrete one, which I think can be useful to prove some results about compactness.

PD: I re-create this post after deleting a previously one expressed in a confusing way.

Comment: "the discrete topology over circles is the discrete one" is a bit trivial, isn't it? You mean: the radial topology restricted to the subspaces that are circles is the discrete topology, presumably.

Comment: @Henno Brandsma Yes, that was what I meant. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $\langle 0,0\rangle\in\operatorname{int}K$ for some compact set $K$; then there is an $\epsilon>0$ such that $\{0\}\times(-\epsilon,\epsilon)\subseteq K$. For each $r\in\Bbb R$ let

$$U_r=\Bbb R^2\setminus\left\{\langle x,x^2+r\rangle\in\Bbb R^2:x\ne 0\right\}\,;$$

then $\mathscr{U}=\{U_r:r\in\Bbb R\}$ is an open cover of $\Bbb R^2$ and hence of $K$, so there is a finite $F\subseteq\Bbb R$ such that $K\subseteq\bigcup_{r\in F}U_r$. But then

$$\{0\}\times(-\epsilon,\epsilon)\subseteq\big(\{0\}\times\Bbb R\big)\cap\bigcup_{r\in F}U_r=\{0\}\times F\,,$$

which is absurd. Thus, $\langle 0,0\rangle$ is not in the interior of any compact set in the radial topology. The space is homogeneous, so no point is in the interior of a compact set, and all compact sets must have empty interior.